# vb.net code to dock the custom tab below the formula bar in excel 2013

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to dock the custom task pane below the formula bar in excel 2013, but some how it's place above the formula bar.

```
 If CustomTaskPanes.Count < 1 Then
        myUserControl1 = New MyUserControl
        myCustomTaskPane = Me.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myUserControl1, "My Task Pane")
        myCustomTaskPane.Visible = True
        With myCustomTaskPane
            .DockPosition = pos.up 
            .DockPosition = pos.Medium

        End With
    End If
```